# Telnetlib: Not receiving anything

Tags: python, telnetlib

I have a question regarding Python`s telnetlib-Library.

```
import telnetlib

message= ('\x02'+'DD'+'\x03')
print message

tn = telnetlib.Telnet('IP','PORT')
tn.write(message)
while True:
   data = tn.read_all()
   if data:
       print data
```

I want to communicate with a data-logger. The data-logger expects commands which looks like this:

STX + command + ETX

By sending the STX+command+ETX-phrase via Putty / telnet to the data-logger, the data logger "answers", e.g. by sending the current time.

Now, I want to send the same thing via python script to the logger. Unfortuantely, I do not receive any answer in the python shell, just a white space.

Can you please help me?

Regard,
Phil

Comment: Just a guess: try adding a `\n` or `\r\n` to the end of the string you're sending. Also use `print repr(data)` to see the exact string that gets returned.

Comment: Another guess: Do you need to log in to the data-logger?

Comment: No. As I mentioned in the original question, all commands are working by submitting them via Putty...

Comment: Is it possible that there is some problem with the tn.read_all()-command **after** the tn.write(message)? Maybe the python-script should listen **before**  the command is submitted?

Comment: I'd be going with @PM2Ring's suggestion. Add a newline to the end of your commands. I've done *exactly* this myself and spent an hour wondering why my instrument is not talking back to me when it does via PuTTY.

Comment: I tried:
message=("\x02" + 'DD' + "\x03" + "\r\n")
However, this seems not to work for me. I guess there is an error by transmitting the newline-command?

Comment: Could you please comment my comment above? 

I tried to send message=("\x02" + 'DD' + "\x03" + "\r\n") However, the result remains the same (the data-logger does not talk back to me). Is there an error with the "\r\n"-statement?

Answer (score -1):

Using doblequote for special character code

> ```
> message= ("\x02"+'DD'+"\x03")
> ```

Have u already declare IP address and port number.

> ```
> tn = telnetlib.Telnet('192.168.0.10',2021)
> ```

Comment: Why do you think that using double-quotes on the string literals would make a difference?